# Selenium unable to locate "app-id-title" element when trying to load google play page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-play

I am trying to run [this code](https://github.com/amrrs/Google-Play-Store-Review-Extractor/blob/master/reviews_extraction.py) to scrape reviews from the google play store - but I keep getting the following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53044/devtools/browser/9de3e58b-6384-4809-bf01-31d47a57879f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Emil/Documents/Guatrain_Reviews/guatrain_reviews.py", line 20, in <module>
    Ptitle = driver.find_element_by_class_name('id-app-title').text.replace(' ','')
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Miniconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Miniconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Miniconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Miniconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"id-app-title"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the id-app-title in

```
Ptitle = driver.find_element_by_class_name('id-app-title').text.replace(' ','')
```

Could someone point out where I would find that Id for the app I am interested in OR help me identify where I am going wrong.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The final result I want needs to look something like this:
[image: Image from github]

where for which ever app url I insert - it will extract the rating and reviews:

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a snap what you want from play store. I'm not able to fine any element with the said class by hitting provided URL

Comment: Ptitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[itemprop=name] span').text

Comment: @QHarr that results in a selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]/div/div"} error.

Comment: It does not result in the error you are showing.

Comment: @QHarr Have you tried your fix in the context of the code in the link?

Comment: Hi, No because that code doesn't look efficient or suitable to scrape all the reviews. Your error is complaining about another line in the code as indicated by the error message. I am simply stating the css selector which works to select the app title for the given url.

Comment: @QHarr okay then. That makes sense It think Thanks for help! Could you then leave your response as an answer saying "the code is not suitable" and give a little more reasoning so I can mark your answer? Would be interested to know why you think this approach is not appropriate.

Comment: Personally, it is because I see use of hard coded values throughout instead of wait conditions, I don't see how the required clicking/scrolling is set up to run until all reviews are generated (you scroll and then click show more on the page), I have a preference for selecting with css selectors over xpath as modern browsers are optimized for css (with some exceptions regarding which is faster influenced by the actual selector combination used (and xpath equivalent) ; how up to date the browser is).... I didn't inspect for long as by then I had decided I would probably write it from scratch.

Comment: @QHarr. That is extremely helpful and makes a lot of sense. I am quite new to this so I genuinely appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries. There are more experienced python people who can probably give more advice/solutions for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is from 2016, so I'm assuming they changed the structure which is why there is no 'id-app-title' or anything from the original code. That's just my assumption.

There's a lot of work that still needs to be done with this code (like changing out the time.sleep for implicit waits by selenium, and quite frankly just to make it more robust, as I only was looking at this particular app review.*EDIT SEE BELOW*) It's really complex html with tons of nested `div` and `span` tags with no specific meaning associated with the attributes/ class, etc. So I had trouble pulling out each user review element.

But essentially, I was able to open the page with the browser, have it continue to scroll down until it can click "Show More", and just continue an x amount of times.

Once it does that, it iterates the span tags. Now I figured out every 10 span tags is relating to a single user. However if the app owner responds to a review, it offsets then by 2 so had to account for that.

I'm fairly newer to programming, so I apologize for messy code and inefficiency. I'm sure an expert would be able to provide a better solution, however, this can hopefully get you started or playing around:

```
#load webdriver function from selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Change this number to get more or less reviews
# Current set of x=100 yielded 11,312 reviews
x = 100

link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.o2.android.myo2&hl=en_GB"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(link + '&showAllReviews=true')

num_clicks = 0
num_scrolls = 0
while num_clicks <= x and num_scrolls <= x*5:
    try:
        show_more = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/content/span')
        show_more.click()
        num_clicks += 1

    except:
        html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        html.send_keys(Keys.END)
        num_scrolls +=1
        time.sleep(2)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
h2 = soup.find_all('h2')

results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for ele in h2:
    if ele.text == 'Reviews':
        c_wiz = ele.parent.parent.find_all('c-wiz')
        for sibling in c_wiz[0].next_siblings:
            try:
                #print (sibling)
                comment_shift = 0
                spans = sibling.find_all('span')
                for user_block in range(0,len(spans)):
                    i = user_block *10
                    name = spans[i+0+comment_shift].text
                    try:
                        rating = spans[i+1+comment_shift].div.next_element['aria-label']
                        rating = str(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, rating)))
                    except:
                        comment_shift += 2
                        continue
                    date = spans[i+2+comment_shift].text
                    review = spans[i+8+comment_shift].text
                    print ('Name: %s\nRating: %s\nDate: %s\nReview: %s\n' %(name, rating, date, review))
                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[date, rating, name, review]], columns = ['Date','Rating','User','Review'])

                    results_df = results_df.append(temp_df)
            except:
                continue

results_df = results_df.reset_index(drop=True)
results_df.to_csv('C:/reviews.csv', index=False)

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df)
                   Date                        ...                                                                     Review
0       31 January 2019                        ...                          Was broken for pay as you go customers. Has no...
1       2 February 2019                        ...                          o2 just won't be happy until their customer se...
2       1 February 2019                        ...                                             Excellent quality piece of kit
3       6 February 2019                        ...                                                                      Gud 
4      23 December 2018                        ...                          Can't get into the app using correct log in de...
5      16 December 2018                        ...                          The update is rubbish. I can't use MyO2 anymor...
6       6 December 2018                        ...                          Stop logging me out with every update, they ad...
7      25 December 2018                        ...                          cant use this app anymore. shame i use to use ...
8      16 December 2018                        ...                          Started receiving texts from 02 immediately af...
9       10 January 2019                        ...                          havent been with the network long nor have i u...
10     22 December 2018                        ...                          update has killed this app. why do I have to p...
11       9 January 2019                        ...                          This app is now unusable for pay as you go cus...
12      26 January 2019                        ...                          Wouldn't it be nice to find an app that the de...
13     19 December 2018                        ...                          wont let me log in now since the latest update...
14      13 January 2019                        ...                          it was ok for a while wen u needed to put in y...
15       6 January 2019                        ...                          from last update I can't login anymore. not ev...
16      24 January 2019                        ...                          I'm having 2 change review again coz I can't g...
17       5 January 2019                        ...                          Changed my rating for this down from five to o...
18     22 December 2018                        ...                          no longer works for me. shame as it was useful...
19      31 January 2019                        ...                          total waste of time since update. not able to ...
20      23 January 2019                        ...                          Despite what the description states the curren...
21     24 December 2018                        ...                          When it finally lets you log in it then says t...
22      17 January 2019                        ...                          Update breaks it, can't log in, log in on webs...
23       5 January 2019                        ...                          02 what have you done to app cant log in chang...
24     30 November 2018                        ...                          Simple easy to use and all info available of m...
25     30 November 2018                        ...                          No longer works for pay and go customers so co...
26      8 December 2018                        ...                          Will not log me in after downloading the lates...
27      15 January 2019                        ...                          Unable to log on to the app since the update. ...
28       1 January 2019                        ...                                     Very easy to use. Keeps me up to date.
29      1 December 2018                        ...                          Good app maybe it should be as colourful as th...
                ...                        ...                                                                        ...
11282  12 February 2017                        ...                          Just re installed this a on my new device.  Ha...
11283  18 December 2016                        ...                          Since updating this app on my Samsung S3 mini ...
11284   19 January 2017                        ...                          Lately the app gives intermittent server error...
11285   7 December 2016                        ...                                                                 New update
11286  12 December 2016                        ...                                                 O2 needs to put right fast
11287  12 February 2017                        ...                          Although unlimited minutes/texts I would still...
11288  30 December 2016                        ...                                                                Never works
11289    13 August 2017                        ...                          I have a Samsung galaxy 7 and the o2 app is no...
11290   6 December 2016                        ...                                                       Doesn't work anymore
11291   4 December 2016                        ...                          Since the last update this app does not work f...
11292   3 December 2016                        ...                                                                         O2
11293   5 December 2016                        ...                                                   Good app (when it opens)
11294   11 January 2017                        ...                                   Stopped working and when it does work...
11295   1 December 2016                        ...                                      Nothing but a blue screen. Not happy.
11296   2 December 2016                        ...                                                             Worst app ever
11297   18 January 2017                        ...                          It's easier than trying to keep track of my ac...
11298  16 February 2017                        ...                          The new update only shows blue screen before t...
11299   15 January 2017                        ...                                                                Mr Dimitrov
11300   8 February 2017                        ...                                                    Code 4 error frequently
11301    4 January 2017                        ...                                                          Won't work at all
11302   27 January 2017                        ...                          O2  GURU  , EXCELLENT, ESQISET  , PHANOMAL, SE...
11303  15 February 2017                        ...                                                         Works well enough.
11304   1 December 2016                        ...                                             Great app keeps you up to.date
11305  28 December 2016                        ...                                                                      My 02
11306  16 December 2016                        ...                                                   This  is  a  "APPY APP""
11307  22 November 2016                        ...                          Doesn't work for business account. Only shows ...
11308  25 November 2016                        ...                                                       Doesn't work anymore
11309  11 November 2016                        ...                          The ap won't open its just a blue screen I've ...
11310  24 November 2016                        ...                                                               Doesn't work
11311  12 November 2016                        ...                                                                      My 02

[11312 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Edit:**

I tried with a couple different links:

```
link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outfit7.mytalkingtom2"
link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ingeniooz.hercule"
```

and it appeared to work:

**Output:**

```
print (results_df)
                  Date                        ...                                                                     Review
0     February 5, 2019                        ...                          after update it is not workin before it was ev...
1     February 4, 2019                        ...                                               no word to describe simply 
2     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                          I loved this game
3     February 6, 2019                        ...                              it is very funny game and very nice game also
4     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                                          
5     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                            relaxing effect
6     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                        this is a cool game
7     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                                  Good game
8     February 6, 2019                        ...                                                                      Beast
9     February 1, 2019                        ...                          Love this game, it is so much better then the ...
10    February 1, 2019                        ...                          The recent updates are epic. The blender and d...
11    February 1, 2019                        ...                          i like this funny game because tom is jumping ...
12    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                      tom 2 is a great game
13    February 3, 2019                        ...                                                        Very very nice game
14    February 3, 2019                        ...                                                        I like it very much
15    February 5, 2019                        ...                                                      Nice and superb game.
16    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                           Tom is a cutipie
17    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                        it is so...... cute
18    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                     tr ty0
19    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                    so good
20    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                  nice game
21    February 1, 2019                        ...                                                                  Nice game
22    February 3, 2019                        ...                                                           i love this game
23    February 6, 2019                        ...                          l love this game as it is fun and enjoyable to...
24    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                    love it
25    February 5, 2019                        ...                                                       it is so awesome 
26    February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                    Amazing
27    February 3, 2019                        ...                                                                       nice
28    February 6, 2019                        ...                                                                       good
29    January 30, 2019                        ...                          Anish Biswa 3 to be a bit. I'm not a good idea...
               ...                        ...                                                                        ...
1770  February 2, 2019                        ...                                                                        fun
1771  February 5, 2019                        ...                                                                       ect,
1772  February 6, 2019                        ...                                                            tom. is so cute
1773  February 6, 2019                        ...                                                                       nice
1774   January 5, 2019                        ...                                                                   urguuhtr
1775  January 14, 2019                        ...                                                  Very interesting game 
1776  January 10, 2019                        ...                                                   It s very very very nice
1777  January 21, 2019                        ...                                                             supab game
1778  January 16, 2019                        ...                                                      it's too funny 
1779  January 20, 2019                        ...                                                              wow Best game
1780  January 27, 2019                        ...                                                             It's damn good
1781  January 28, 2019                        ...                          this a good and supper game. very nice game. ,...
1782  February 4, 2019                        ...                                       i love this game very very very much
1783   January 5, 2019                        ...                                                                      super
1784  January 12, 2019                        ...                                                               It's fun Lol
1785  January 16, 2019                        ...                                                              it ,s so good
1786  January 23, 2019                        ...                                              fun game for kids....loved it
1787  January 27, 2019                        ...                                                               It's so nice
1788  February 1, 2019                        ...                                            Nice The Baby games i like 
1789  January 29, 2019                        ...                                            it's funny and it's fun to play
1790  January 10, 2019                        ...                                                       best game... so cute
1791  January 10, 2019                        ...                                                                   So Cute!
1792  January 24, 2019                        ...                                        i lv this game very nice game .....
1793  January 25, 2019                        ...                                        Its superb... I love this game... 
1794  January 27, 2019                        ...                                          It is best game ever played
1795  January 19, 2019                        ...                                                                 I love it!
1796  January 20, 2019                        ...                                                                 good game!
1797  January 16, 2019                        ...                                                        i love this game .
1798  January 25, 2019                        ...                                            It is a good game for kids.....
1799  January 31, 2019                        ...                                                   my talking tom is fun

[1800 rows x 4 columns]
```

And

```
print (results_df)
                  Date                        ...                                                                     Review
0     December 2, 2018                        ...                          It's a very well-thought-out an all rounded ap...
1      January 1, 2019                        ...                          L'application est superbe et hyper complète! B...
2     December 6, 2017                        ...                          Great workout diary with statistics. Easy to u...
3        June 13, 2017                        ...                          I love this app! I've tried so many others, bu...
4       March 28, 2017                        ...                          Works great at what it does. You can add exerc...
5       March 21, 2017                        ...                                                                      Great
6     December 8, 2016                        ...                               Has all I need to build & adjust my workouts
7     October 23, 2016                        ...                                                                    Goodish
8   September 23, 2016                        ...                                                                  Great app
9        July 18, 2016                        ...                                                                  Excellent
10       March 9, 2016                        ...                                                                 great app.
11       July 10, 2015                        ...                                                    Amazing and easy to use
12        June 5, 2015                        ...                          I dreamt of this app, Hercule made it. Best ap...
13      March 18, 2015                        ...                                                        Really good, but...

[14 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it needs a slightly improvement. Change 8 to 12 and you will get reviews.

```py
review = spans[i+12+comment_shift].text
```